# Powershell and a C# Connection Broker

Tags: c#, powershell, terminal-services

We have a problem using a C# script to configure the connection broker with the Powershell.

When we import the module `remotedesktopservices`, because the session host role was installed and used before, then install the connection broker role, we have to restart our script to get the right output.

We can reproduce the behavior if we use the Powershell directly.

These are the commands we call:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module servermanager
PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module remotedesktopservices
PS C:\Windows\system32> add-windowsfeature rds-connection-broker

Success Restart Needed Exit Code Feature Result
------- -------------- --------- --------------
True  No       Success  {Remotedesktop-ConnectionBroker}

PS C:\Windows\system32> ls rds:

  Directory: RDS:

Name              Type   CurrentValue     GP  PermissibleValues PermissibleOperations
----              ----   ------------     --  ----------------- ---------------------
RDSConfiguration        Container           -           Get-Item, Get-ChildItem
RemoteApp           Container           -           Get-Item, Get-ChildItem

PS C:\Windows\system32> import-module -force remotedesktopservices
PS C:\Windows\system32> ls rds:

  Directory: RDS:

Name              Type   CurrentValue     GP  PermissibleValues PermissibleOperations
----              ----   ------------     --  ----------------- ---------------------
RDSConfiguration        Container           -           Get-Item, Get-ChildItem
RemoteApp           Container           -           Get-Item, Get-ChildItem
```

After a restart of the Powershell, or our programm, the result looks (correctly) like this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ls rds:

  Directory: RDS:

Name              Type   CurrentValue     GP  PermissibleValues PermissibleOperations
----              ----   ------------     --  ----------------- ---------------------
RDSConfiguration        Container           -           Get-Item, Get-ChildItem
RDSFarms            Container           -           Get-Item, Get-ChildItem
RemoteApp           Container           -           Get-Item, Get-ChildItem
ConnectionBroker        Container           -           Get-Item, Get-ChildItem
```

We need this output without a restart of our program.
Is it possible to get a fresh new Powershell in C#? "remove-module" and "import-module" did not help.

This is our C# code to get the Powershell runspace:

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
iss.ThrowOnRunspaceOpenError = true;
iss.ImportPSModule(initialRoles);

RemoteHost.powerShellRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
RemoteHost.powerShellRunspace.Open();
```

Even if we create a new powershell runspace in the same way, it seems the old Powershell is loaded

Comment: Can you show more code, specifically how you are creating RemoteHost?

Answer (score 0):

There is Power Shell Class in C sharp have a look at that. It provides all most all the functionality of Power Shell. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.powershell%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can refresh power shell also.

Let me know if this will solve your problem, or something from my side.